# Does pytmx provide you with a way to tell if an image has been rotated, flipped horizontally/diag working with Tiled?

Tags: python, tiled, pytmx

I am making a game using pygame and Tiled to design the map. I am able to load the tiles and blit them on to the screen. When i flip the tile horizontally/rotate inside of Tiled and run the game, the tiles are not rotated inside of the game.

So i would want to check if the tile is rotated/flipped before blitting the tile onto the screen and i am not sure how exactly to do this or whether if this is even possible and proceed to use the tiles without any rotations or flips inside of Tiled?

I read that there are flags you can check for, but at this point i am not sure of that either, any help would  be great. Heres the class used to make the map

```
import pytmx

class TiledMap:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename)
        self.width = tm.width * tm.tilewidth
        self.height = tm.height * tm.tileheight
        self.tmxdata = tm

    def render(self, surface):
        ti = self.tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
        for layer in self.tmxdata.visible_layers:
            if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x, y, gid, in layer:
                    tile = ti(gid)
                    if tile:
                        # check for flags first.. ie rotating, flips
                        # do the neccessary transformations... this part i know
                        # blit the transformed tile

                        # if no flags just blit the image
                        surface.blit(tile, (x * self.tmxdata.tilewidth,
                                                    y * self.tmxdata.tileheight))
```

how the same tile flipped horizontally appears inside of Tiled

[image]

how the image gets loaded when i run the game

[image]

---

Okay so after reading [Tile flipping](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/latest/reference/tmx-map-format/#tile-flipping), here's what i understood from it.

- Get the gid

Already have that from this bit of code `for x, y, gid, in layer:`

- Check for the flags

> The highest three bits of the gid store the flipped states.

Says that 32nd bit is for horizontal flip. So to check for that we do `h_flipped = gid & (1<<31) # correct?` But the problem here is when i do that it evaluates to a `0`. Printing out the gids gives `1` for the unflipped tile and `2` for the flipped so `2 & (1<<31) # false`

The pseudo code was a bit confusing and maybe i understood it incorrectly. So either the gids i am getting is incorrect or the checking for the bit is incorrect? or Both? More help appreciated

Comment: Which TMX library is the code using?  Using `pytmx`, the rotation is handled automatically - requesting the tile image returns a pre-rotated version.  I've not used "Simple TMX Library", but this has `tmx.object.properties`.  Perhaps the rotation is stored in there, it is certainly one of the class initialisation parameters.

Comment: What is the value of `gid`? Tiled encodes the [flipping flags](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/latest/reference/tmx-map-format/#tile-flipping) in the global tile ID, so maybe they're still in there.

Comment: i am using pytmx. And the value of the gid is 1 for not flipped and 2 for flipped